# How Export fpspread to Excel vb6?

Tags: vb6

I try to export to Excel with the fpsread plugin, but there really is no information on how, I have searched the manual but they only show me how to do it with .net

Will someone have an idea?

Comment: Could you post the code you have tried?

Answer (score 1):

I managed to do it was very simple, but wanting to import the titles was the heaviest, but here I leave the code in case any work

```
Private Sub CmdImportar_Click()
    Call Export_Excel(cdgExcel, sprFacturas)
    Call HacerBusqueda
End Sub

Public Sub Export_Excel(cdgExcel As CommonDialog, Spread As fpSpread)
Dim Header() As String
Dim I As Integer
Dim j As Integer
Dim x As Integer

With cdgExcel
 .CancelError = False
 .InitDir = "C:/:"
 .Filter = "Excel(*.xls)|*.xls"
 .ShowSave

     If .filename <> "" Then
        Spread.Redraw = False
        For I = 1 To Spread.ColHeaderRows

            ReDim Header(Spread.MaxCols) As String
                Spread.Row = SpreadHeader + (I - 1)
            For j = 1 To Spread.MaxCols
              Spread.Col = j
              Header(j) = Spread.Text & ""
            Next j

            Spread.MaxRows = Spread.MaxRows + 1
            Spread.Row = I
            Spread.Action = ActionInsertRow
            For j = 1 To Spread.MaxCols
                Spread.Col = j
                Spread.CellType = Spread.CellType
                Spread.TypeHAlign = Spread.TypeHAlign
                Spread.TypeVAlign = Spread.TypeVAlign
                Spread.Text = Header(j) & ""
            Next j
        Next I

    x = Spread.ExportToExcel(.filename, "Sheet1", "")

     For I = 1 To Spread.ColHeaderRows
        Spread.Row = 1
        Spread.Action = ActionDeleteRow
     Next I


    If x = True Then
        MsgBox .filename & vbNewLine & "Se ha Importado el archivo", vbInformation, "Resultado"
    Else
        MsgBox "No se ha podido exportar el archivo", vbCritical, "Error"
    End If
  End If
End With
End Sub
```